# proguard-project.txt not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am new to Android and Android Studio.

During my learning I came across the Google Play Services for Ads and all.

I tried to enable proguard in my project but reading the below link **[proguard](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)**.

The problem is that I am not able to find **proguard-project.txt** or **proguard.cfg** in my project structure...

Instead there is a **proguard-rules.txt** in my project structure...

How can I find these missing files and configure proguard in my project...

**Please help**...

Comment: Did you create proguard-rules.txt yourself, or was it generated?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the **proguard-rules.txt** file instead. Proguard doesn't attach any special significance to the name of its rule input files; it uses whatever's set up in your build files, which for new projects created in recent versions of Android Studio, is:

```
buildTypes {
     release {
         runProguard false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
 }
```

The **proguard-android.txt** file lives inside your SDK, and contains reasonable Android-wide defaults that all projects should use.

Comment: Where does proguard-rules.txt live?

Comment: In more modern versions of Android Studio, the New Project Wizard creates a proguard-rules.pro file in your application module directory.

Comment: I guess my project code is old.  And even though I update my Android Studio regularly, it won't create proguard-rules.pro automatically...

Comment: Yes, in my case it won't create too. I copied proguard-rules.pro from empty project created by New Project Wizard.

Comment: Even when creating a new project in Android Studio it does not generate this proguard-rules.txt as far as I can see... And I have the most recent version of android studio.

Comment: hey what is this ? its not working. plz send me demo

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem when I started using **Android Studio**

You can't see the `ProGuard` files because you are previewing you project in a non `Project file` mode. Which most probably will be `Android` view mode.

## [image]

You have to change the mode by clicking on the drop down list of the Android selection and select `Project Files` to see all the files in the project as the following:

### [image]

Then you will be able to see the hidden files in the `Android` project structure view mode.

### [image]

And here is a good [example](https://gist.github.com/Jackgris/c4a71328b1ae346cba04) for the `ProGuard`

Comment: Great answer. Could you please tell me while .pro changes to .txt because I tried this but not changed the extension?

Comment: @VVB I'm not sure which OS you are using, but most of them when you replace the file extension ask you if you want just to change the file name or the file extension.. Just make sure that you are not changing the file name only.. I hope this helps

Answer (score 22):

You can find *proguard-project.txt* or other ProGuard files in:

`C:\Users\"USER"\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\proguard`

Or: `C:\Users\"USER"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\proguard`

Replace `"USER"` with your actual username under *C:\Users*.

For macOS, look under `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard`.

Comment: thankyou jesus.  someone ACTUALLY JUST SAID WHERE THE F IT IS.

Comment: For Linux users it's similar, usually `~\Android\sdk\tools\proguard`. Also, why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: just to add , for MAC the path will be `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard`

Answer (score 9):

the code posted previously must be corrected to the following according to your use:

```
buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled true  //according to your use
         // or
         minifyEnabled false //according to your use
         // runProguard false ** NOT USED ANYMORE, replaced by minifyEnabled
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find this proguard-rules.txt anywhere on my Windows machine with Android Studio. I did however find a LayoutExample\app\proguard-rules.pro file. This is probably because I had imported my project from Eclipse, so Android Studio didn't create one automatically. So what I did was:

1 - Copy the proguard-rules.pro from the example project to the same folder as build.gradle for my project (you can either search for this file on your machine or create an empty project)

2 - Edit the code in build.gradle to use this file instead of proguard-rules.txt, e.g.

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

3. Sync gradle, then Build > Build APK. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

**proguard-rules.txt** can be found with terminal command on OS X (should be similar on windows as well)

```
$ locate proguard-rules.txt
```

On my machine the output is:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/AndroidWearModule/root/proguard-rules.txt.ftl
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/proguard-rules.txt.ftl
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidTVModule/root/proguard-rules.txt.ftl
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewGlassModule/root/proguard-rules.txt.ftl
```

You can place this file by removing the extra extension beyond txt. Here is what it looks like so you can create your own and place in your android project.

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdkDir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating android studio , I couldn't import my project to new version.
 change in the gradle build file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false *//change to this not runProguard false*
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```